# On page I declared a js variable, include js file can't seem to access it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            var SOME_ID= 234;

        });

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= HtmlExtension.ScriptFile("~/somefile.js") %>"></script>
```

The .js file just uses the SOME_ID value, but I'm getting an error saying SOME_ID is not defined.

Shouldn't this work in theory?

Comment: If you move your var outside of document ready, does it work as expected?

Answer (score 6):

You've declared a local variable within the anonymous function. If you want it to be a global variable, use `window.SOME_ID = 234;` instead, or move it out of the anonymous function.

E.g., either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        window.SOME_ID= 234;

    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SOME_ID= 234;
    $(document).ready(function () { 

    });
</script>
```

**Either way**, the external file can access it as either `SOME_ID` (unqualified) or `window.SOME_ID`, because global variables are properties of the global object (which is `window` on browsers).

Comment: NOTE: While using window is safe in the browser, it is not always the global context for javascript.

Comment: @Hemlock: The "global variable object," you mean. ;-) And yes, that's absolutely true. In non-browser environments, the global variable object may be completely anonymous, or may have another name. This is fairly obviously a browser environment, but still, worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a local variable inside an anonymous function which will be accessible only inside this function. You need to declare it outside:

```
var SOME_ID = 0;
$(function () { 
    SOME_ID = 234;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is defined inside the scope of your anonymous function. Move it outside of the ready handler and it ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

This variable is scoped to the Function Expression (FE) passed to the `ready` method - it will not be available outside this scope.

You need to make the var global if you want other scripts to be able to access it:

```
var SOME_ID;
$(document).ready(function () { 
   SOME_ID = 234;
});
```